# Delimited Filename Parsed into Table Row Data

Tags: php, filenames, delimited

I am attempting to convert variable width, pipe (|) delimited file names into table data.

E.g.

```
var1|var2|var3|var4|var5.pdf
```

becomes

```
<table border="2" bordercolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td>$var1</td>
        <td>$var2</td>
        <td>$var3</td>
        <td>$var4</td>
        <td>$var5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have everything up to, and after `var1` but cannot figure out how to parse the remaining variables out. 
This is where I have tossed the towel and decided to post here:

```
$var1 = substr($file_name, 0, strpos($file_name, '|'));
```

Ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can put all the fields in an array using [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), like this:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$data = "var1|var2|var3|var4|var5.pdf";
$fields = explode("|", $data);
var_dump($fields);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "var1" [1]=> string(4) "var2" [2]=> string(4) "var3" [3]=> string(4) "var4" [4]=> string(8) "var5.pdf" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list()` in conjuction with `explode()` if you want each value in its separate variable, like this:

```
list($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5) = explode('|', $filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you explode the filenames into an array rather than creating variables for each one, but I have given example code on how to achieve this anyway. I hope I answered your question correctly.

```
<?php
    $string = 'var1|var2|var3|var4|var5.pdf';
    // Trim the string of dangling pipes to make sure we don't get empty array elements.
    $string = trim($string, '|');
    // Split the filenames into an array. Much more managable that way.
    $filenames = explode('|', $string);
    // Define an empty array to put our variables in.
    $variables = array();
    // Because the array we made is not associative we can iterate through with a for loop.
    for($i = 0; $i < count($filenames); $i++) {
        // Make our variable names start from one; much more human-friendly. Add them to an array to extract later.
        $var_name = 'var' . ($i + 1);
        $variables[$var_name] = $filenames[$i];
    }
    // Extract the values of the array and place them into variables named after the array keys.
    extract($variables, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
```

This will create the following variables (along with their values).

```
$var1 = 'var1';
$var2 = 'var2';
$var3 = 'var3';
$var4 = 'var4';
$var5 = 'var5.pdf';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$parts_arr = explode('|', $filename);
var_dump($parts_arr);
```

Also, pipes are special characters in just about every shell I can think of, I strongly recommend *not* using them in a file name.